# No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/ + Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x2d000005 (code=1)

Tags: android, streaming, live

i'm struggling since a month to add buils mpegts isomedia compliant audio file on android without succees . i took this library in c++ on github and adapted the main method to use it with java via shared lib.

```
extern "C" JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_isomedia_cmd_mpegtscmd_executecopy(JNIEnv *env, jclass cls, std::string *in_file, std::string *out_file )
```

{

```
const char* in_file_name = in_file->c_str();
const char* out_file_name = out_file->c_str();

std::cout << "input ts: " << in_file_name << std::endl;
std::cout << "output ts: " << out_file_name << std::endl;

std::ifstream ifile(in_file_name, std::ios::binary | std::ios::in); // declare un flux permettant de lire dans input file
std::ofstream outts(out_file_name, std::ios::binary); // declare un flux pour ecrire dans output file

std::tr1::shared_ptr<MpegTsMuxer> muxer(new MpegTsMuxer);

MpegTsDemuxer demuxer;
char packet[188] = { 0 };

SimpleBuffer in;
SimpleBuffer out;

while (!ifile.eof()) {
    ifile.read(packet, 188);
    in.append(packet, 188);

    TsFrame *frame = 0; //nullptr; You can only use nullptr in Visual Studio 2010 and newer, it is a C++11 feature.
    demuxer.decode(&in, frame);

    write_file(frame);
    if (frame) {
        muxer->encode(frame, demuxer.stream_pid_map, &out);
        outts.write(out.data(), out.size());
        out.erase(out.size());
    }
}

ifile.close();
for (auto it = file_map.begin(); it != file_map.end(); it++) {
    it->second->close();
}

return 0;
```

}

after load library in java i call the method like this

```
mpegtscmd.executecopy(f_in.getAbsolutePath(),f_out.getAbsolutePath());
```

the both files is created in the same directory but no data fill the program crash with error

```
No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/ +  Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x2d000005 (code=1)
```

what i try to do is to read AAC_ADTS_data in the f_in file to add TS packet and put in f_out . i precise that when i record f_in solely data are  writting in f_in without problem. thanks for any expected support.

Comment: So, have you tried [implementing `JNI_OnLoad`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html#JNJI_OnLoad)?

Comment: thakns @Michael you have put me on the right way to solve this issue i realise that there are another methode to link native to java soi will  try stuff base on this two link  https://www.cnblogs.com/keis/archive/2011/04/12/2013174.html and https://christina404.com/2018/03/04/Android-JNI/ gracias senior